# Filling Array with unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

Pretty basic question here I think but not one I could find an answer for - I have a bunch of arrays that I want to extract unique values from. Each array has a list of skills a candidate is proficient in and I want to build an array that lists all skills that have been listed.

This is the code I have which lists a persons name and the skills they have:

```
const people = [
  { name: "Mike", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java", "Python"] },
  { name: "Bob", skills: ["Python", "Java"] },
];
```

What I want to do is build an array with each skill listed above only appearing once, no matter how many times its in the arrays above. I  have tried using the Set feature as follows:

```
let options = [...new Set(people)]
```

but that dosent work for me. Ideally I want the output to be something like:

```
options["JavaScript", "Java", "Python"]
```

where each unique value is represented only once. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine all skills to a single array with [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), convert to a Set to get only unique values, and then spread back to an array:

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Mike", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java", "Python"] },
  { name: "Bob", skills: ["Python", "Java"] },
];

const skills = [...new Set(people.flatMap(o => o.skills))];

console.log(skills);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lodash` .

Then, you can use  `_.difference(array1,array2);`

Goodluck !

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is fine, but you need to add the `skills` to the set, no the entire people objects. One approach to solve this is to traverse every array of skills while add they to the set:

```js
const people = [
  {name: "Mike", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java", "Python"]},
  {name: "Bob", skills: ["Python", "Java"]},
];

let skills = new Set();
people.forEach(p => p.skills.forEach(s => skills.add(s)));
console.log("skills => ", [...skills]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also add a polyfill to this .flatMap(), because this is not supported by IE at all.

```js
if (!Array.prototype.flatMap) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "flatMap", {
    value: function(callback, thisArg) {
      return this.map(callback, thisArg).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
}

const people = [
  { name: "Mike", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java", "Python"] },
  { name: "Bob", skills: ["Python", "Java"] },
];

const skills = [...new Set(people.flatMap(o => o.skills))];

console.log(skills);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below of using reduce and Set

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Mike", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java", "Python"] },
  { name: "Bob", skills: ["Python", "Java"] },
];

console.log(people.reduce((acc, v) => {
   acc.push(...v.skills)
   return [...new Set(acc)]
}, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

Way more verbose than it needs to be, but:

```
for (let individual of people) {
  for (let skill of individual.skills) {
    options.indexOf(skill) < 0 ? options.push(skill) : '';
  }
}
```

Could do it.